# CKEditor 4 ensure that every image is surrounded by its own paragraph

Tags: ckeditor

I need to make sure, that every image in CKEditor 4 is surrounded by its own paragraph.
Is it possible to prevent that two or more images are surrounded by the same paragraph ?
I tried solving this serverside but would prefer a solution right in the editor.